# JAVA AWS Machine Learning API to enable Realtime prediction

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, machine-learning

Can someone help me with name of api which enables realtime prediction of a model. Please note that i am not requesting for RealtimeEndpointRequest object. i have gone through the entire documentation of AWS [Machine Learning SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/machinelearning/model/package-summary.html) but haven't found any thing.

**Edit 1** :
This is the code that i have used -

```
        CreateRealTimePrediction createRealTimePrediction ; 
        CreateRealtimeEndpointRequest createRealtimeEndPointReq;
        CreateRealtimeEndpointResult createRealtimeEndPointRes;
        PredictRequest predReq;
        String mlModelId="ml-Lkqmcs8cM2W";
        createRealtimeEndPointReq.setMLModelId(mlModelId);
        PredictResult predRes = null;
        Map<String,String> record=null;
        // assume i have set a record in the Map.
        createRealtimeEndPointRes = amlClient.createRealtimeEndpoint(createRealtimeEndPointReq); 
        String predictEndpoint=createRealtimeEndPointRes.getRealtimeEndpointInfo().getEndpointUrl();

        predReq= new PredictRequest();
        predReq.setMLModelId(mlModelId);
        for (int i=0;i<recordKeys.length;i++){
            record.put(recordKeys[i],recordValues[i]);
        }
        predReq.setRecord(record);
        predReq.setPredictEndpoint(predictEndpoint);
        predRes=amlClient.predict(predReq);
        return predRes;      
  }
```

Now what is happening is - if i enable the real time prediction by using aws management console manually and then run this segment of code, then the results are generated as expected but when i the realtime prediction is disabled, then i get this error -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.machinelearning.model.PredictorNotMountedException: Either ML Model with id ml-Lkqmcs8
cM2W is not enabled for real-time predictions or the MLModelId is invalid. (Service: AmazonMachineLearning; Status Code: 400; Error Code
: PredictorNotMountedException; Request ID: 2dc70e58-07d0-11e5-a0c7-bb93f17d1b2e)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1160)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:748)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:467)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:302)
        at com.amazonaws.services.machinelearning.AmazonMachineLearningClient.invoke(AmazonMachineLearningClient.java:1995)
        at com.amazonaws.services.machinelearning.AmazonMachineLearningClient.predict(AmazonMachineLearningClient.java:637)
        at com.nrift.aml.prediction.realtime.CreateRealTimePrediction.createRealTimePrediction(CreateRealTimePrediction.java:61)
        at RealTimePrediction.main(RealTimePrediction.java:53)
```

which effectively means that this segment of code is not enabling the real time prediction though i have used

```
CreateRealtimeEndpoint
```

api in it.

P.s- the code segment i have posted is a not complete, the complete code is working correctly so you can make assumptions about the correctness of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you are looking for is [CreateRealtimeEndpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRealtimeEndpoint.html). Creating a real-time endpoint is the mechanism for enabling the model to be used for real-time predictions. When you no longer need to use this model, you can destroy the endpoint with the [DeleteRealtimeEndpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteRealtimeEndpoint.html) API. The model always stays intact, so you can create/delete endpoints when needed.

Comment: please see Edit 1 in the question i have added some more details.